# change the role of a user to another role in laravel 8

Tags: pivot-table, laravel-8, user-permissions, user-roles

i want to change the role of a user and from one role to another role but I am getting an error that says:

> Trying to get property 'Role_name' of non-object

[image: Trying to get property 'Role_name' of non-object]

this is my update function in the controller
public function update(Request $request,User $user )
{

```
    $role=Role::where('Role_name',$request->rolename)->first();
    if($role->Role_name!=='Normal user' && $user->is_admin=1){
        $user->roles()->sync($role);
    }
    elseif($role->Role_name!=='Normal user' && $user->is_admin=1){
        $user->roles()->sync($role);
        $user->update(['is_admin'=>0]);
    }
    return redirect( url('admin/admins') )->with('success','Ucwords($user->name) has been Updated Successfully');
    
}
```

[image: update function]

and also this is the blade view

[image: bladeview]

I have not understood where the problem is because it's returning an error. this is my roles table

[image: roles table]

my users table

[image: users table]

How I can solve this?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your code. If someone would like to help you and copy your code... he/she can't do that from a picture.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure $role is always set, you can use firstOrFail();

```
$role = Role::where('Role_name',$request->rolename)->firstOrFail();
```

Probably the variable is not set, this will make sure that it is not null;

Comment: its returns an error of 404 not found even when i dd($role)

Comment: this is how i was able to debug i changed the 'Role_name' to 'id'. 
 from      $role=Role::where('Role_name',$request->rolename)->first();
  to          $role=Role::where('id',$request->rolename)->first();  as I have set the value as an id

Answer (score 0):

in your select tag roles, your value is id so in controller it should be like this.

```
$role = Role::findOrFail($request->rolename);
```